# Delphi : How to change the size of ScrollBar

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, delphi-xe

I want to change the size of ScrollBars of a TScrollBox

I have changed "Size" and "ButtonSize" and "Style = ssFlat or ssHotTrack" but no changes affected !

I want to make it thinner !

How can I do that ? Should I change the System Metrics ?

I`m using Delphi XE6 and Windows 8

Comment: We don't know what styling options you are using. VCL Styles, or not? The standard Windows theme? XP themed, or classic v5.8 comctl32. Most likely it's the standard theme and Windows decides this for you. If you want to make your application look at home on the platform you should accept that, and stop tinkering. If you want to follow the lead set by Winamp, from way back when, then tinker away with VCL styles.

Comment: I`m using VCL Style, I just want to change the Scrollbar size and nothing else, just want to change some available properties of ScrollBox but there is no change; I have tried InitializeFlatSB() on the CreateWND Proc but no chance !

Comment: Which style are you using?

Comment: The only Style I have changed is ScrollBars's Style to ssFlat ( or ssHotTrack ) and other Styles are Default values and I'm using AdvScrollBox of TMS Components; but maybe I don`t understand your mean of Style !

Comment: No, I don't think you do understand what I mean when I refer to VCL Styles. Perhaps you might search for that term. And now you reveal that you are using a TMS control. Given the confusion, I'm going to give up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Oh ! Excuse me !, I'm not using VCL Styles; I have tried to use VCL Styles for changing the ScrollBars a few ago but Styles have effects on all components and I don't know how to prevent that because I want to change just ScrollBars and nothing else

Comment: As I found out there is no an Application-wide solution and I should change system metrics, or use an TScrollBar that not is a good solution !; I solved my problem with a skin component, thanks @DavidHeffernan

Comment: What's wrong with having your application look native?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : There is no problem but this is what my customer wants

Comment: Good to see the customers focusing on the stuff that matters!!  ;-)